# get no data from Axios & curl call to specific site

Tags: node.js, curl, axios

I try to get data from [enter link description here](http://web.humoruniv.com/board/humor/list.html?table=pick) < this site.
I've got nothing when i made axios call to that site.

Thus I've done `curl -I url` to get the status. ( return 200)
( curled -K -X and I've got nothing. )

I have no idea of it to track the problem down.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please share your code where you're using axios

Comment: sorry

http://web.humoruniv.com/board/humor/list.html?table=pick